# Как заставить telegram бота проверять реагировать на сообщения из google sheets?

Tags: telegram, google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Всем привет! Кто может подсказать, как сделать так, чтоб при написании боту например сообщения "привет", "пока" , "жизнь" google script проверял совпадение текста в столбце google таблицы. Если например в ячейке C2, C3, C4 находятся слова "привет", "пока" , "жизнь", тогда бот отвечает текстом из ячеек B2, B3 и B4 соответственно?

У меня есть код, который заставляет реагировать на конкретное сообщение в коде, но не в гугл таблице.

```js
const API_TOKEN = 'token';
const ssId = 'idtabl';
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);
const telegramUrl = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + API_TOKEN;
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('').getSheetByName('');
function doPost(e) {
  const update = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);

  const cmdSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Лист1');
  const cmdValues = cmdSheet
    .getRange(2, 1, cmdSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 3)
    .getValues();
  const cmds = cmdValues.map((row) => row[2]);

  if (update.hasOwnProperty('message')) {
    const msg = update.message;
    const chatId = msg.chat.id;

    const messageText = (msg.text || '') + (msg.caption || '');
    const user = msg.from.hasOwnProperty('username') ? msg.from.username : '';

    const userFirstName = msg.from.first_name;
    const userLastName = msg.from.last_name;

    const data = [
      [new Date(), user, chatId, userFirstName, userLastName, messageText],
    ];
    if (msg.text == 'привет') {
      const payload = {
        method: 'sendMessage',
        chat_id: String(-519944610),
        text:
          msg.text +
          ' ' +
          '<strong>' +
          'айди ' +
          '</strong>\n' +
          ' ' +
          chatId +
          ' ' +
          'юзернейм' +
          ' ' +
          '@' +
          user +
          ' ' +
          userFirstName +
          ' ' +
          userLastName,
        parse_mode: 'HTML',
      };
      const opts = {
        method: 'post',
        payload: payload,
      };
      UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + API_TOKEN + '/', opts);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте функцию поиска, например,

```js
/**
 *
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.Sheet} sheet
 * @param {string} msg
 * @returns {string | undefined}
 */
function getReplyFromSheet_(sheet, msg) {
  const row = sheet
    //.getDataRange()
    .getRange('A2:C4')              // По условию вопроса
    .getValues()
    .find((row) => row[2] === msg); // Индекс 2 - колонка C
  return row ? row[1] : undefined;  // Индекс 1 - колонка B
}
```

Теперь в коде бота вы сможете получить требуемый ответ.

```js
// ... your master code before
const payload = {
  method: 'sendMessage',
  chat_id: String(-519944610),
  text: getReplyFromSheet_(sheet, msg.text) || 'Ни шиша не найдено',
  parse_mode: 'HTML',
};
// ... your master code after
```

Comment: Спасибо! Разобрался, сделал!

Comment: А не подскажешь еще, как можно сделать, чтоб ответ бота был: первая строка ячейка A2 , вторая строка B2 (условно)? Т.е , если я пишу так: .find((row) => row[2] == msg); // Индекс 2 - колонка C
  return row ? row[0] +  row[1]: undefined;  // Индекс 1 - колонка B  . То все пишется в одну строку.

Comment: Хм... По идее, код должен возвращать значение одной ячейки. Т.е. можно вывести что-то вроде `return row ? \`${row[0]} ${row[1]}\` : undefined;`

Comment: Все равно в строчку пишется.

Comment: Решил проблему, нужно добавить:  /n